# Find all polygons containing a point in PostGIS

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, geolocation, postgis

I've managed to get a list of all points contained in a specific polygon, but how can I query a PostGIS database to find out what polygons contain a given point?

Suppose I have a table `places` with lat/lon locations (`POINT` types) and a `areas` table with a `geometry` column with `MULTIPOLYGON` types.

How can I write a query that will return a list of places and all the areas that contain each point? For example:

```
place_id, area_ids
1, {23,425,536}
2, {30,425}
-- etc...
```

Comment: St_contains without array_agg, will not produce the array output, as you stated in your question, just to be clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `array_agg` in conjunction with [ST_Contains](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Contains.html), see [aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html) for more on array_agg and similar functions. If you combine this with a group by on your points table, you will get an array of all the polygons containing those points, eg,

```
SELECT pl.id, array_agg(ar.id ORDER BY ar.id) as area_list
FROM areas ar, places pl 
WHERE ST_Contains(ar.geom, pl.geom) 
GROUP BY pl.id
ORDER BY pl.id;
```

Note, you can put an Order By inside array_agg, so that the area IDs always appear in the same order. I have called both table's primary keys, id, and both table's geometries, geom, so you might have to adjust for your set up.

Comment: Perfect! Adjusted the primary key names and geometries and it's working great :-)

Comment: Glad to help. Arrays are very helpful with spatial.